# Android app wont run

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

Please help me understand why my app isn't running.
I want to check if the swiping works or not, but it won't even start on the emulator.
Since I'm very new to androing programming, I cannot find what is wrong as there are not compiler errors.

Acitivity code:
    package enn.ericsson.sitezoeker;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ViewFlipper viewFlipper = GlobalVars.viewFlipper;
    Animation slideLeftIn = GlobalVars.slideLeftIn;
    Animation slideLeftOut = GlobalVars.slideLeftOut;
    Animation slideRightIn = GlobalVars.slideRightIn;
    Animation slideRightOut = GlobalVars.slideRightOut;
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = GlobalVars.gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = GlobalVars.gestureListener;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
        slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
        slideRightIn = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
        slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.slide_right_out);

        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,
                (OnGestureListener) gestureListener);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

GlobarVars.java:
    package enn.ericsson.sitezoeker;

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class GlobalVars extends Application {

    private static GlobalVars vars;

    public static GlobalVars getInstance() {
        return vars;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        vars = this;
    }

    public static GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    public static View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    public static Animation slideLeftIn;
    public static Animation slideLeftOut;
    public static Animation slideRightIn;
    public static Animation slideRightOut;
    public static ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

}
```

MyGestureDetector class:
    package enn.ericsson.sitezoeker;

```
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    ViewFlipper viewFlipper = GlobalVars.viewFlipper;
    Animation slideLeftIn = GlobalVars.slideLeftIn;
    Animation slideLeftOut = GlobalVars.slideLeftOut;
    Animation slideRightIn = GlobalVars.slideRightIn;
    Animation slideRightOut = GlobalVars.slideRightOut;

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        try {

            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name=".GlobalVars"
    package="enn.ericsson.sitezoeker"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="me.user_interface.DisplayMessageActivity"/> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout:

```
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/View1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Provider:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbKPN"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="KPN" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbTMobile"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="T-Mobile" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbVodafone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Vodafone" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Site number:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtSitenr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" >
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Address:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblAddress"
                    android:layout_width="231dp"
                    android:layout_height="71dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/draw"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" >
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="City:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblCity"
                android:layout_width="231dp"
                android:layout_height="71dp"
                android:background="@drawable/draw"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:id="@+id/View2" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView31"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Site name:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblSiteName"
                android:layout_width="231dp"
                android:layout_height="71dp"
                android:background="@drawable/draw"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp" >
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView41"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Site type:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblSiteType"
                android:layout_width="231dp"
                android:layout_height="71dp"
                android:background="@drawable/draw"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp" >
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>

</ViewFlipper>
```

rg,
Eric

Comment: If it's crashing, you need to find and post the logcat message that displays when you get the error. It should be some 10-50 line stack trace.

Comment: Do you honestly expect for someone to sift through all of this and guess the compiler error that you are getting? If you're going to copy and paste your entire application's source code, the least you could do is provide us with a stack trace, an explanation of the expected behavior vs. the behavior you are getting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I only checked a few lines of code, but I noticed that you are not calling `super.onCreate()` (and your `onCreate` method should be `public` not `protected`):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Failing to call `super.onCreate()` throws a SuperNotCalledException. From the `onCreate` documentation:

> *Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.*

If you still need help, you need to post your new LogCat errors.

Answer (score 0):

In the main activity change the `"public abstract class mainActivity"` to `"public class mainActivity"`
Then change `"protected void onCreate"` to `"public void onCreate`.You should also include `"super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);"` in the onCreate class in the main activity.Guess that should work just fine.

Comment: Hi,

I have changed to code as suggested by Sam and Mungaih.
I have added the CatLog to the post because for me there is no change.

So I must still be doing something wrong.

rg,
Eric

Comment: @Eric - I don't see the LogCat in your post, please make sure you added it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working.
The problem was the GestureDetector stuff.
It wasn't even calling the class and I have removed both and used the TouchListener method.

It's now swiping, but just once, so not completely fixed, but getting there... :-)